# Creating a texture from a RGBA value with SlimDX

Tags: c#, slimdx, texture2d

this is my first post to stack overflow!
I'm using SlimDX for a game that my team is making and I've run into an issue. I'm trying to create a ShaderResourceView from RGBA values in a Color4 object. I've searched looked for answers to my issue and this is as far as I have gotten.

```
    private ShaderResourceView GetTexture(Device device, int width, int height, Color4 color)
    {
        //create the texture
        Texture2D texture = null;
        Texture2DDescription desc2 = new Texture2DDescription();
        desc2.SampleDescription = new SlimDX.DXGI.SampleDescription(1, 0); 
        desc2.Width = width;
        desc2.Height = height;
        desc2.MipLevels = 1;
        desc2.ArraySize = 1;
        desc2.Format = SlimDX.DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm;
        desc2.Usage = ResourceUsage.Dynamic;
        desc2.BindFlags = BindFlags.ShaderResource;
        desc2.CpuAccessFlags = CpuAccessFlags.Write;
        texture = new Texture2D(device, desc2);


        // fill the texture with rgba values
        DataRectangle rect = texture.Map(0, MapMode.WriteDiscard, MapFlags.None);
        if (rect.Data.CanWrite)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < texture.Description.Height; row++)
            {
                int rowStart = row * rect.Pitch;
                rect.Data.Seek(rowStart, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                for (int col = 0; col < texture.Description.Width; col++)
                {
                    rect.Data.WriteByte((byte)color.Red);
                    rect.Data.WriteByte((byte)color.Green);
                    rect.Data.WriteByte((byte)color.Blue);
                    rect.Data.WriteByte((byte)color.Alpha);
                }
            }
        }
        texture.Unmap(0);

        // create shader resource that is what the renderer needs
        ShaderResourceViewDescription desc = new ShaderResourceViewDescription();
        desc.Format = texture.Description.Format;
        desc.Dimension = ShaderResourceViewDimension.Texture2D;
        desc.MostDetailedMip = 0;
        desc.MipLevels = 1;
        ShaderResourceView srv = new ShaderResourceView(device, texture, desc);

        return srv;
    }
```

I believe that the texture's data is being set but I can't be sure because nothing is being displayed. I know that my renderer works as I can load texture from a file perfectly fine but I seem to have a problem that I cannot find. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: If you are having issues with rendering content using SlimDX, you can use [PIX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manders/archive/2006/12/15/a-painless-introduction-to-pix-for-windows.aspx) to debug the actual pixels. It can be useful to see the pixel history in cases where you are getting unexpected behaviour, such as nothing appearing on the screen. Note, though, that you can only debug a 32-bit version of SlimDX using PIX.

Comment: Hi. I can see you asked this a while ago, but I'm new to DirectX and SlimDX and was wondering if you could let me know how you initialized your device for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the code right all along. I feel like an idiot but I found out my problem, I wasn't setting the alpha value for the texture so it was actually being drawn I just couldn't see it >_<; Simple mistakes always eh? Thanks to all that viewed however.